# MS Access to C# connection Visual Studio 13.. can't find what is wrong?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, database-connection

It is giving system.collections.listdictionaryinternal error, but can't figure out why. I have followed a video on youtube for this code and the tutor had written the same code and it was executed properly. Please help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace SundayApp
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        OleDbConnection con = new  oleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data     Source=c:\users\owner\searches\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\SundayApp\SundayApp\Sunday.accdb");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = string.Format("INSERT into studentinfo values {0},{1}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        OleDbCommand c = new OleDbCommand(s, con);
        try { c.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
        catch (Exception ee) { MessageBox.Show( ee.Data); }
        MessageBox.Show("Data Added");
        c.Dispose();
    }



    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: [Exception.data is a dictionary, you will have to loop through it to display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Or you could change it to just the message `MessageBox.Show( ee.Message);`

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL syntax appears to be missing the parenthesis around the value arguments.

```
string s = string.Format("INSERT into studentinfo values ({0},{1})", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
```

If this is not it, can you please post the stack trace, so we can see what line is generating the error. Thanks.